# Performing t-test loop over columns in a dataframe: ERROR variables differ in length

Tags: r, t-test

I have an issue with performing a t-test over all columns of my dataframe.

1. What I want to do?
   Each column represents a KPI of a certain research question. Moreover each column can be divided into two groups target = 1 and non-target = 0, defined in the "target" column. I want to perform a t-test per column between those two groups and save the p-value and t-value in a separate dataframe.
2. Below you can find a code which would work, there would be no error message. However I would need to type the code below 70 times column by column and always change the column name (below "X1y_ret"), which is not convenient as I have those 70 columns in my dataframe.

   `t.test(X1y_ret ~ target, data = analysis_matched_targets_all, var.equal = FALSE)$p.value`
3. That's why I tried to use a for loop to make it more convenient. You can find the code below. However it doesn't work, giving me an error message of different variable lengths (found for 'target').

```
for(i in colnames(analysis_matched_targets_all) { 
    statistics_all_types_all_year[3, which(colnames(analysis_matched_targets_all)==i )] <- t.test(i ~ target, data = analysis_matched_targets_all, var.equal = FALSE)$p.value}
```

I would really appreciate if you could help me with my problem :)

Comment: Try the formula `get(i) ~ target`. As is `i` is a character string, whether it holds the name of a data set column or any other string is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I've focused my answer on your part 2 that seems to be at the heart of what you wish you knew. How to iterate , apply a function many times, over different input parameters.

```
#invent a dataset, not with 70 vars to t.test, but with 2

(sleep_with_more_vars <- mutate(sleep,
                               anothervar=rev(extra)))

# show how we would by hand do each of the 2 
t.test(extra  ~ group, data = sleep_with_more_vars, var.equal = FALSE)$p.value
t.test(anothervar  ~ group, data = sleep_with_more_vars, var.equal = FALSE)$p.value

# show how we would do them programatically, just by naming them
vars_to_do <- c("extra",
                "anothervar")

(results <- lapply(vars_to_do, function(x)t.test(as.formula(paste0(x ," ~ group")),
                                          data = sleep_with_more_vars, var.equal = FALSE)$p.value))

names(results) <- vars_to_do

results
```